# How to check datetime datatype in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Upgrade pandas version to 1.0.4, then I see this exception. Suggestions?

```
AttributeError: module 'pandas.core.dtypes.common' has no attribute 'is_datetimelike'
```

My code looks like

```
if pd.core.dtypes.common.is_datetimelike(column)
```

I do not see error when running "`pip install`"

What is the difference "`pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype`" and "`pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype`"?

Solution:  "`pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype`"

Comment: what caused this error? What code? Or do you get than when you run 'pip install' or something similar?

Comment: Can you check [`is_datetime64_any_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_any_dtype.html) ?

Comment: It works. Thank you

Comment: @susanne - Super, added to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function does not appear to be part of pandas 1.0.4.

Doesn't `pandas.core.dtypes.common.is_datetime_or_timedelta_dtype`
do what you need?

Run `help(pandas.core.dtypes.common.is_datetime_or_timedelta_dtype)` to get information on it.

Alternatively, `pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype` may suit your needs:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_datetime64_dtype.html